# how to remove duplicates from the map using java

Tags: java

I am adding few item on finalMapNode using map for creating json for d3. and i dont want any duplicates item. how to check.finalmapNode put the duplicates item on map.I dont want duplicated item.if item is avalible then it should not put on map .                       if id is avalable then item should not put in the finalmapnode.

Note::if id is avalable then item should not put in the finalmapnode.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listNodeMap = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
Map<String, Object> finalMapNode2 = new TreeMap<String, Object>();
    Map<String, Object> finalMapNode = new TreeMap<String, Object>();


                   //if id is avalable then item should not put in the finalmapnode.

                    finalMapNode.put("id", Integer.parseInt(source2.get(z))+"");
                    finalMapNode.put("name",source.get(z));
                    finalMapNode.put("displayname", source.get(z));
                    finalMapNode.put("image", "/xxxxx/resources/icon/location.png");
                    finalMapNode.put("type", "location");
                    finalMapNode.put("group", 0);
                    finalMapNode.put("opacity", 100);

                    finalMapNode2.put("id", Integer.parseInt(target2.get(z))+"");
                    finalMapNode2.put("name",target.get(z));
                    finalMapNode2.put("displayname", target.get(z));
                    finalMapNode2.put("image", "/xxxxx/resources/icon/location.png");
                    finalMapNode2.put("type", "location");
                    finalMapNode2.put("group", 0);
                    finalMapNode2.put("opacity", 100);

                listNodeMap.add(finalMapNode);
                listNodeMap.add(finalMapNode2);
```

Comment: Duplicate keys or duplicate values?  A `Map` can't support multiple/duplicate keys...

Comment: Also, your question would benefit from an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem in as little code as possible.

Comment: i dont want any id,name,displayname,image,type,group,if that id is available on that.

Comment: What do you mean "if that id is available on that"?

Comment: @Boann by checking through conditon

Comment: @RakhiSsdd What condition? What do you mean "available", and what is "that"?

Comment: @MadProgrammer can i check before puttting on it

Comment: @Boann i dont know. that's the problem.

Comment: `Map#containsKey`...

Comment: @MadProgrammer it has multiplekey like id,name,display etc ?? how to check.

Comment: You can only have one key per map.  If you want to check the other maps, then you will need to loop each map and use `Map#containsKey`...

Comment: I'm sure there's a simple solution, if you'd explain what you mean by "id is available on that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to add the KEY which is already available in the hashmap, then it will override the previous KEY's VALUE and adds the new VALUE. So its up to you to validate the map before trying to add the KEY and VALUE. You can use **finalmapnode.containsKey(KEY);** to validate and then add the VALUES.

**EDIT**

Just check the below method works for you!

```
private static void putMap(String strKey, Object object, Map<String, Object> map){
    if(!map.containsKey(strKey)){
        map.put(strKey, object);
    }
}
```

In your case, instead of using

```
finalMapNode.put("name",source.get(z));
```

you can use

```
putMap("name",source.get(z), finalMapNode);
```

The above method will not override the values if you add duplicate KEYS. Pass the **KEY**, **VALUE** and the **Map** which you declared as **finalMapNode**.

Try this and see.

Thanks!

Comment: how to do that it has multiple key how to get one key can you write the code ??

Comment: @RakhiSsdd I have added an EDIT in my **Answer**. Just check.

Comment: what is param on putMap(String strKey, Object object, Map<String, Object> map) or what putmap return.

Comment: @RakhiSsdd its a **void** method and it will not return anything. so add this method in your class where ever you use **finalMapNode** Map, and call this method by passing KEYS, VALUES and MAP which you initialized earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("A", "1");
            map.put("B", "2");
            map.put("C", "2");
            map.put("D", "3");
            map.put("E", "3");
            HashMap<String, String> mapNew = new HashMap<String, String>();
            
                for(String s :map.keySet())
                {
                    //String value = map.get(s);
                    System.out.println(s +"=="+map.get(s));
                    
                    if(!mapNew.containsValue(map.get(s)))
                    {
                        mapNew.put(s, map.get(s));
                    }
                 }
                System.out.println(mapNew);
```

before :{A=1,B=2,c=2,D=3,E=3}

Output after removing duplicates : {A=1,B=2,D=3}

Comment: You could improve the quality of your answer by giving some explanation. See the accepted answer for example.